# Comando similar ao convert do sql em c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Tenho um retorno em sql que vem como algo do tipo `52,451541554`.

Esse retorno, se eu converto ele com o comando `convert(datetime, DtCriacao, 103)` do *sql* ele vira um formato de data, só que estou precisando pegar esse mesmo, que dessa vez veio de um arquivo do excel e converter ele pro formato de data ou *string*.

Não tenho menor ideia como fazer esse tipo de conversão no c#.

Obrigado

Comment: `52,451541554` esse valor são apenas as horas? minutos? você quer adicionar à data atual??

Comment: 05/09/2017 16:15... isso que ele é

Comment: no caso é um `timestamp`!?

Comment: Creio eu que sim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que o valor recebido do *bd* é um `timestamp`, você precisa convertê-lo em *data* e então exibir na formatação correspondente ao `103` do *sql* (`dd/mm/yyyy`):

```
string valorSql = "52,451541554";
System.DateTime data = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
data = data.AddSeconds(valorSql);
string retorno = data.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Quem é esse dateTime?

Comment: ops, erro meu. Alterei a resposta

Comment: Cara, ele está me retornando 01/01/1970 12:57:24

Comment: `convert(datetime, DtCriacao, 103)` esse é o código que você usaria no sql. Quem é `datetime` (data atual?) e `DtCriacao` (esse valor?) ??

Comment: datetime -> o tipo e dt criação o meu 52,45...

Comment: perguntei porque rodando o código `select convert(datetime, '52451541554', 103)` me retorna um erro (`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75502/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-rlinhares).

Comment: Roda esse "42983,6773691319" no lugar do '52451541554'

Comment: Pequena alteração da resposta mas achei a solução baseada no que ele passou         double sla = Double.Parse(xlworksheet2.Range["B4"].FormulaLocal);
                    DateTime date = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddDays(sla - 2);